# Нужно ли клиенту устанавливать базу данных

Tags: java, база-данных, javafx, hibernate, spring-boot

Я в программировании еще молод. Сейчас я пишу диплом на java, суть которого реализация задачи о рюкзаке, только в промышленном масштабе(задача об упаковке контейнеров). Допустим я использую ORM, в моем случае Hibernate(пока только постигаю азы) для создания базы данных. Я использую postgres. В конечном итоге у меня будет готовый .exe, если я его запущу на другом компьютере, заработает ли поддержка БД? А возможно я слишком зеленый и задал глупый вопрос, тогда просветите, как такие программы обрабатывают массивы данных?
Чтобы например в моей программе данные в таблицу добавлялись из бд и им не был страшен reboot.
[image: Моя программа]

Comment: если не прибегать к танцам с бубном, то в результате компиляции кода, написанного на java , вы получите не exe, а jar файл, который может быть исполняемым. база данных не имеет ничего общего. это готовое решение и вы подбираете ее под свои требования. если это сервер, то она устанавливается на сервере, как это и происходит с Postgresql. Но вы используете JavaFX, скорее всего, пишите дескотопное приложение. в таком случае стоит посмотреть на embedded решения, например derby. они не настолько производительны, но зато не требуют установки.

Comment: Спасибо! Нагуглил, теперь знаю в какую сторону двигаться!

Comment: да не за что, удачи